# Solving using the master theorem: T(n)=T(n/2)+n⋅log n and T(n)=T(n/8)+2.n

Tags: algorithms, master-theorem

Could someone help me with these 2 questions?

I do not understand the case 3

1. $T(n) = T(n/2) + n \log n$
2. $T(n)=T(n/8)+2 n$

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Could you please add some more detail to your question so as to narrow it a little bit? Bluntly stating "I do not understand the case 3" does not give potential answerers much to work with (except explaining the entire master theorem in detail). Also, please add any attempts you have made at solving the two questions so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show you how to solve these without using the master theorem. For the first item:

$$
T(n) = n\log n + \frac{n}{2} \log \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{4} \log \frac{n}{4} + \cdots \leq \left(n + \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{4} + \cdots\right) \log n \leq 2n\log n.
$$
This shows that $T(n) = O(n\log n)$. Since clearly $T(n) = \Omega(n\log n)$, we can conclude that $T(n) = \Theta(n \log n)$.

The second item can be solved in the same way.